# Stopping version purge in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

We are running version purge manually in AEM repository occasionaly. When this is being done, the segment store size grows exponentially. So is there way to stop version purge activity from the backend (server) or front end (UI) inbetween? Because I see only the Start button in the version purge console and not a Stop/Kill button and I'm assuming restarting the AEM instance is the only way to kill version purge activity which should not be an ideal case. Please share your inputs.

Comment: You can compact the instance after the purge if the segment store size is a concern.

Comment: True. But is there a way to stop the version purge in between?

Comment: You can configure how often it should be executed. Take a look here: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/deploying/configuring/version-purging.html